Debugging makefiles with overriden arguments
I'm trying to understand the following target and why it's done this way:
Top-level makefile and target:
collect:
    file_list="file_list.txt"
    for makefile in $(ALL_PROJECTS) ; do \
        $(MAKE) -s -f $$(basename $$makefile) --directory=$$(dirname $$makefile) GetDependenciesFile RELATIVE_DIR="$$(dirname $$makefile)" DEPENDENCIES_FILE="$$file_list"; \
    done;

Makefile that contains the target I'm trying to understand:
.PHONY: GetDependenciesFile
$(if $(filter GetDependenciesFile, $(.OVERRIDEN)),OVERRIDEN,) GetDependenciesFile: DependenciesFile.tmp
ifeq ("$(DEPENDENCIES_FILE)","")
    echo "DEPENDENCIES_FILE is not specified"
else
    cat DependenciesFile.tmp >> $(DEPENDENCIES_FILE)
endif


DependenciesFile.tmp:
    echo "$(ALL_DEPENDENCIES)" >> DependenciesFile.tmp

This is a simplified version of what I'm dealing with (I removed sed and other steps that are obvious, like sorting and removing duplicates).
I understand that the goal is to traverse all makefiles contained in $(ALL_PROJECTS), and within each makefile append the contents of the variable $(ALL_DEPENDENCIES) to DependenciesFile.tmp, the contents of which then appended to $(DEPENDENCIES_FILE) which is file_list.txt from the top-level target.
What I don't understand is this specific line:
$(if $(filter GetDependenciesFile, $(.OVERRIDEN)),OVERRIDEN,) GetDependenciesFile: DependenciesFile.tmp

I tried to grep OVERRIDEN in makefiles but couldn't find anything.
I don't understand what's happening when the result of if is evaluated and why it's placed before the target name.
Any suggestions?

Note that as presented in the question. the recipe line file_list="file_list.txt" is useless.  It sets a shell variable in a shell that then terminates immediately.  There does not appear to be any attempt to reference that variable anyway, in either makefile fragment, so I can't even guess at what the point (if any) was supposed to be.

The variable .OVERRIDEN begins with a . which means it's in the reserved variable space for make: however, that is not a standard variable in GNU Make (and it's misspelled anyway: the right spelling would be .OVERRIDDEN if it existed, which it doesn't).  So this must be something invented by your makefile environment.  If you can't find it, I have no idea.  You can add a $(info OVERRIDEN = '$(.OVERRIDEN)') into you rmakefile at that location to see what, if anything, it's set to.

But, what that if-statement does is check to see if the string GetDependenciesFile exists in the value of the variable .OVERRIDEN and if it does, the if-statement is replaced with the string OVERRIDEN and if it doesn't, it's replaced with the empty string.  In this context, it will result in either an extra target OVERRIDEN being defined that depends on DependenciesFile.tmp, or not.  I can't begin to guess what the point of that is.

@JohnBollinger "file_list.txt" - that was a typo, I added $$

@MadScientist this is a very old and messy codebase, OVERRIDEN is indeed with one D, and there's a good chance that this solution is unnecessarily overcomplicated. The goal is to collect dependencies from each makefile for a backup. The dependencies are taken from a variable $(ALL_DEPENDENCIES) in a DependenciesFile.tmp recipe. To my understanding, that's all it's supposed to do

@MadScientist I'll try $(info OVERRIDEN = '$(.OVERRIDEN)'), thanks!


What I don't understand is this specific line:
$(if $(filter GetDependenciesFile, $(.OVERRIDEN)),OVERRIDEN,) GetDependenciesFile: DependenciesFile.tmp


The $(if ...) is a GNU make "function" that expands conditionally based on the arguments within (functions and function expansion are a GNU extension to standard make).  The syntax is:
$(if condition,then-part[,else-part])

The condition part is considered true if stripping preceding and trailing whitespace and then expanding whatever is left results in a non-empty string.  In that case, the then-part is evaluated to produce the expansion of the if.  Otherwise, the else-part is evaluated to produce the expansion, where not providing that part of the conditional is equivalent to providing an empty string.
In your case, the condition is $(filter GetDependenciesFile, $(.OVERRIDEN)), the then-part is OVERRIDEN, and the else-part is (explicitly) empty.
The $(filter ...) is another GNU make function.  The syntax is:
$(filter pattern...,text)

, where patterns are expressed in a syntax idiosyncratic to GNU make. The effect is to split the text on whitespace, and expand to all of the resulting words that match any of the specified patterns, joined by whitespace.
In your case, only one pattern is given, GetDependenciesFile.  The text to be filtered is the expansion of make variable .OVERRIDEN.  Thus, if GetDependenciesFile appears as a whole word in the value of $(.OVERRIDEN) then

the $(filter) expression expands to GetDependenciesFile,
making the condition of the surrounding $(if) true, so
the $(if) expands to OVERRIDEN.

Otherwise,

the $(filter) expands to nothing,
making the $(if) condition is false, so
the $(if) expands to nothing.


I don't understand what's happening when the result of if is evaluated and why it's placed before the target name.

Regular make rules can have multiple targets, expressed as a whitespace-delimited list.  The $(if) is placed so that when it expands to anything other than whitespace, that will be interpreted as one or more additional targets for the rule.
A rule with multiple targets expresses that each specified target depends on all the specified prerequisites, and that it can be built, individually, via the given recipe.  Thus, when your $(if) expands to OVERRIDEN, the result is that the rule for GetDependenciesFile can also be used to build a target named OVERRIDEN.
The recipe does not actually create a file with either name, so unless such a file is created by other means, each of those targets will always be considered out of date.  My best guess is that the intent is to allow the recipe to be executed twice with some of the makefiles, once for target GetDependenciesFile, and once for target OVERRIDEN, whereas it is executed at most once with other makefiles.  There are other possibilities related to building target OVERRIDEN, too, depending on the circumstances under which that is done.

Thank you for the answer, it's much clearer now. What still confuses me is that OVERRIDEN is not referenced anywhere in makefiles except this line. I tried to echo $(OVERRIDEN) but I haven't seen anything except an empty string yet (the codebase has multiple top makefiles meant to produce different distributions and I haven't tried all possible options). But if it's not referenced anywhere (and it's 100% not passed as an argument), then $(.OVERRIDEN) is always nothing, and there will be no second target - is that correct?

As I mentioned in another comment: there's a chance that this was added 20 years ago for a purpose that no longer exists, but I have to figure everything out now

@user23743938, make variables can be read from the environment (but not .OVERRIDEN specifically) or set via the command line when you launch make. And you can specify targets to build on the command line, too.  Thus, not finding any sign in the makefiles themselves that these are used is inconclusive.  It's also a question of how these makefiles are used in your various scripts and workflows.
